# How do I do a PHP insert for two or more separate MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

The HTML:

```
<html> 
<?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\paxdb\head.php';  
include 'config/menu.php';?>  
<div id="dataentry"> 

<!--This section is the demographic text field area--> 
<form method="post" action="dataentered.php"> 
First Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="First_Name"/></br> 
</br> 
Last Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Last_Name"/></br> 
</br> 
E-mail:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email"/></br> 
</br> 

<!--This section is the age range checkbox selection area--> 
<p><u><b>Age Range</b></u></p> 
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="20-25" value="20-25"/>&nbsp;20-25</br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="26-30" value="26-30"/>&nbsp;26-30</br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="31-35" value="31-35"/>&nbsp;31-35</br> 
</div> 
<div id="checkboxes"> 
</div> 

<!--This section is the trips take checkbox area--> 
<div id="tripstodatetype"> 
<p><u><b>WHAT TYPE OF TRIPS TO DATE HAVE YOU TAKEN?</b></u></p> 
<input type="checkbox" name="trip2date[]" id="Bus" value="Bus">&nbsp;Bus&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="trip2date[]" id="Car" value="Car">&nbsp;Car</br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="trip2date[]" id="Weekend fly-in" value="Weekend fly-in">&nbsp;Weekend fly-in&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br> 
</div> 
<div id="tripstodateborder"> 
</div> 

<!--This section is the type of trip client likes best checkbox area--> 
    <div id="triplikebest"> 
<p><u><b>WHAT TYPE OF TRIP DO YOU LIKE BEST?</b></u></p> 
<input type="checkbox" name="triplikebest[]" value="Bus">&nbsp;Bus&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="triplikebest[]" value="Car">&nbsp;Car</br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="triplikebest[]" value="Weekend fly-in">&nbsp;Weekend fly-in&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br> 
</div> 
<div id="triplikeborder"> 
</div>
```

**and the PHP:**

```
<html>
<?php
include 'head.php';
include 'config/menu.php'; 
$host="localhost";
$username="somename";
$password="somepass";
$dbname="pax";

$dbc = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname); 
if (!$dbc) 
{ 
    die('Error connecting to MySQL server' . mysql_error()); 
    } 
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbc); 

$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['First_Name']);  
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Last_Name']); 
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
$age = $_POST['age']; 
$my_range = ""; 
foreach($age as $range) { 
   $my_range = $my_range . mysql_real_escape_string($range) . ", "; 
} 
$trip2date = $_POST['trip2date'];
$my_triprange = ""; 
foreach($trip2date as $triprange) { 
   $my_triprange = $my_triprange . mysql_real_escape_string($triprange) . ", "; 
} 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pax` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `email`, `age`,`trip2date`)    
     VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email', '$my_range','$my_triprange')")  
     or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_close($dbc); 
?> 
<div class = "entered">
 <p>Success! Your Data Has Been Submitted.  Please click on <b>'DATA ENTRY'</b> above to enter another. </P>
 </div>
    <?php include 'footer.php';?>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**If I were to put the triprange data into a separate table, how would I convert the INSERT query to perform the insert into the new table? (let's say the new/second table is called 'trip').  -OR- Does it make more sense to use a second INSERT query here?  If so, how should it appear to remain connected to the first table/ID**

thank you in advance.

Comment: your edit put you on the right track...  you want a one to many relatinoship between the user info and the trips.  This requires an index that is shared between the two.  (unique ID for each user, and add that id in the trips table for reference)

Comment: ok, So, if I were to put this 'multi' answer data into a second table, how would I adjust the insert query to include data entered into the 2nd table or does it make more sense to just write a 2nd insert query?

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, are you trying to enter the same data twice into different tables?

if not you should make your query a variable, so the line would read something like this...

```
$query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pax` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `email`, `age`,`trip2date`)    
     VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email', '$my_range','$my_triprange')")  
     or die(mysql_error());
```

you could look into repeating the insert statement for another table but use the same variables declared in the original code.

if i am on the wrong lines, could you maybe explain a little more?

Comment: Sorry - you may have missed my edits to my question.  My $my_triprange data has the possibility for the survey responsant to answer with selecting multiple checkboxes.  So, this means the answer entered into the table could be one, two, or all three answers.  So, I'm thinking of putting this into another table (primarily to learn how this is done for later projects I may attempt) and the question is do I, now, need a second insert query or is there a better way to just concatenate the 2nd table to the existing insert query?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_multi_query();
```

Read the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

EDIT:

```
<?php

  /* connection conf */
  // use p: if you want to have a persistent connection 
  // this will improve the speed and resource usage of opening a connection
  $host     = "p:localhost";
  $username = "somename";
  $password = "somepass";
  $dbname   = "pax";

  /* make connection */
  $lnk = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  /* prepare variables */
  $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['First_Name']);  
  $last_name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Last_Name']); 
  $email      = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
  $age        = $_POST['age']; 

  $my_range = ""; 
  foreach($age as $range) { 
    $my_range = $my_range . mysqli_real_escape_string($range) . ", "; 
  }

  $trip2date = $_POST['trip2date'];
  $my_triprange = ""; 
  foreach($trip2date as $triprange) { 
     $my_triprange = $my_triprange . mysqli_real_escape_string($triprange) . ", "; 
  }

  /* execute query */
  mysqli_query($lnk, "INSERT INTO `pax` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `email`, `age`,`trip2date`) " .
                     "VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email', '$my_range','$my_triprange');"
               );  

  /* execute multi query INSERT */
  mysqli_multi_query($lnk, "INSERT INTO `pax` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `email`, `age`,`trip2date`) " .
                           "VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email', '$my_range','$my_triprange');"
                           "COMMIT;"
                     );  

  /* execute multi query SELECT */
  $query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
  $query .= "SELECT `email` FROM `pax` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5";

  if (mysqli_multi_query($lnk, $query)) {
    do {
      /* store first result set */
      if ($result = mysqli_store_result($lnk)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
          printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
      /* print divider */
      if (mysqli_more_results($lnk))
       printf("-----------------\n");

    } while (mysqli_next_result($lnk));
  }  

  /* close conenction */
  mysqli_close($dbc); 

  // I used your code and some samples from the PHP manual.
  // Hope this piece of code helps you and others to understand mysqli better.
  // Thanks to PHP for having the best manual.

?>
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually find that their manual just serves to confuse  me more than when I started.  It's easier for me to understand if I can see the potential solution using my own sample code (I can see the changes quicker and understand what each change does).  I'm an extreme novice at this as this is my first ever database.

Comment: If this is your first database you should consider re-writing it from scratch ad the mysql_ functions you are using will be deprecated soon. You need to rewrite everything using mysqli_.

Comment: Thanks - this will be kept as local host and users barely know excel much less PHP; so, I am not so concerned about SQL injection - frankly, after install on the server, they can delete it and I would feel nothing less than pride.  So, how do I incorporate/use your suggested 'mysqli_multi_query();'?

Comment: Well you still need to convert everything to mysqli_commands. They are similar except for the fact that the connection has to be stored in a variable and then that variable is the first parameter in most commands. Use the procedural example here to get an understanding: http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php Then check out the multi-query part.

Comment: Thanks - now how would I go about performing the insert into a second table and keeping the same link to the first table (or would this matter if a foreign key were used?)... i.e. say there's a second table called `trip` and the auto-increment of`trip_ID` and VALUE `trip2date` and perhaps the foreign key `pax_id` were stored there. Would I need to code a separate INSERT query or could I concatenate the second table to the first INSERT query?

Comment: Check out the example I posted. It shows how multi_query works. All you need to do is add bought inserts to the same string that is executed on mysql. Insert 1; INSERT2;....INSERT x; It is just like running two separate inserts. The only diffrence in this case is that they are sent as a single statement to MySQL.